# Working in Visual Studio on a blank App trying to link a .js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova

I am new to Web development and Visual Studio. I have currently created a new a blank App(Apache Cordova) project. I have created two files, a html and javascript. I have the current code in the html as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Todo List Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Budget presentation</li>
    <li>Email Directors</li>
    <li>Warranty docmentation for sox</li>

</ul>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</html>
```

In the javascript file the code is currently
    alert("THIS IS A LNIKED FILE");

When I click on the Simulate in Browers, the url is http://localhost:4400/index.html
When I check the console in the simulated browsers is see an error message of GET http://localhost:4400/index.html/demo.js and no alert pops up.

When I check the path of the javescript c:\users\Bach\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\blankcordovaapp1\blankcordovaapp1\www\scripts\demo.js. What am I doing wrong that the simulator will connect to my javascript file.

Hope this question was clear enough, please advise if you have further concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript file is in a different folder to your index.

Your `index.html` file is in the `www` folder and your `demo.js` file is in the `www/scripts` folder.

As such, to correctly reference your JavaScript file, you're looking for one of the following:

- `src="/scripts/demo.js"` (**root**-relative to document root `www`)
- `src="scripts/demo.js"` (**document**-relative)

More information absolute absolute, root-relative and document-relative links can be found **[here](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/linking-navigation.html)**.

Hope this helps! :)